# SQL Server How do I link these tables?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get information out of two table that don't quite match

In `table1` I have sales data like this:

```
OrderNo   Qty  Price 
--------------------
12345      2    123
```

In `table2` I have data that relates to the same order, but instead of one line with a quantity of two, I have two individual lines:

```
OrderNo   Line   Qty   SerialNo
--------------------------------
12345      1      1      6789
12345      2      1      6790
```

What I would like to see is info from both tables - I have the pricing data in `Table1` and serial numbers in `Table2` and I'm trying to create a report that shows pricing for the total order but also serial numbers for each individual line.

So far, using left joins, I've only been able to get data coming back with duplicate records, the above example returns four lines, two lines for each serial number.

For the above example, what I'd like to see is three lines; one header line containing the total price of the two lines from `table1` (with a null `serialNo`) and two more lines from `Table2` with Nulls for the price, is this posible?

Here's an example....

ADEPT.dbo.SM_MOVEMENTS is my table1 - 
SAM.dbo.productspurchased is table2

```
   ` select

Adept.dbo.STK_MOVEMENTS.SM_REFERENCE,
SAM.dbo.productspurchased.adeptref,
Adept.dbo.STK_MOVEMENTS.SM_costprice,
Adept.dbo.STK_MOVEMENTS.SM_Quantity,
Adept.dbo.STK_MOVEMENTS.SM_Stock_code,
SAM.dbo.productspurchased.fullproductcode,
SAM.dbo.productspurchased.SerialNo

from

adept.dbo.STK_MOVEMENTS left join SAM.dbo.productspurchased on
Adept.dbo.STK_MOVEMENTS.SM_REFERENCE COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as = SAM.dbo.productspurchased.adeptref COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as

where 

SM_REFERENCE = '184913'`
```

For this example order 184913 has a qty of three in ADEPT and three lines of one in SAM.

I get the folling results...

```
SM_REFERENCE    adeptref    SM_costprice    SM_Quantity SM_Stock_code   fullproductcode SerialNo
184913  184913  89.72   1   I-EN-M-SOC  I-EN-M-SOC    2071639819 | PRODUCT KEY: LBB6V-UKJ3D-NC6EN-3G3C3-RQJQH
184913  184913  89.72   1   I-EN-M-SOC  I-EN-M-SOC    2071639819 | PRODUCT KEY: LBB6V-UKJ3D-NC6EN-3G3C3-RQJQH
184913  184913  89.72   1   I-EN-M-SOC  I-EN-M-SOC    2071639819 | PRODUCT KEY: LBB6V-UKJ3D-NC6EN-3G3C3-RQJQH
184913  184913  89.72   1   I-EN-M-SOC  I-EN-M-SOC  Serial Number:  2071639820 | Product Key: SJVBS-GJ7J5-8VP4H-9RQPP-R6RWN
184913  184913  89.72   1   I-EN-M-SOC  I-EN-M-SOC  Serial Number:  2071639820 | Product Key: SJVBS-GJ7J5-8VP4H-9RQPP-R6RWN
184913  184913  89.72   1   I-EN-M-SOC  I-EN-M-SOC  Serial Number:  2071639820 | Product Key: SJVBS-GJ7J5-8VP4H-9RQPP-R6RWN
184913  184913  89.72   1   I-EN-M-SOC  I-EN-M-SOC  Serial Number:  2071639819 | Product Key: LBB6V-UKJ3D-NC6EN-3G3C3-RQJQH
184913  184913  89.72   1   I-EN-M-SOC  I-EN-M-SOC  Serial Number:  2071639819 | Product Key: LBB6V-UKJ3D-NC6EN-3G3C3-RQJQH
184913  184913  89.72   1   I-EN-M-SOC  I-EN-M-SOC  Serial Number:  2071639819 | Product Key: LBB6V-UKJ3D-NC6EN-3G3C3-RQJQH
```

As you can see nine lines in total.

I'm not that great at joins!

Comment: Why don't you give an example of your LEFT JOIN queries and we can advise where you are going wrong?

Comment: It wont give 4 records if you use left outer join correctly. If you use left outer join correctly on order number you will get two rows for each line from table2 (price column will be duplicate for each row)

Comment: ....just wondering if anyone has any suggestions now that I have posted the code?